# Get Common Hash Ref in Perl

Tags: perl, hash, grep

I have a hash like this.

```
my $records = {
'Name' => [
{ A => 101},
{ B => 102},
{ B => 102},
{ C => 104},
{ C => 104},
],
};
```

Now i want to get the the hash refs that are repeated like B => 102 is repeated i  want to get that rest i want to leave .

I want to get all the hash ref that are repeated.
In the final response .

Response out i want is like this :

```
$records = {
'Name' => [
{ B => 102},
{ C => 104},
],
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that hashes with repeated keys have only one key/value pair,

```
my $records = {
  'Name' => [
    { A => 101},
    { B => 102},
    { B => 102},
    { C => 104},
    { C => 104},
  ],
};

my %seen;
@{ $records->{Name} } = grep {
  my ($k) = keys %$_;
  # approve only keys which are seen second time,
  # as this qualifies them as duplicates
  ++$seen{$k} ==2 
}
@{ $records->{Name} };
```

Comment: i want to handle this if more than one times value exists

Comment: if keys are like this { B => 102},{ B => 102},{ B => 102}, then it will not work i hope

Comment: if can please elaborate this a little more to me will be thank full to u .I am just a beginner in perl

Comment: @GauravPandey `$_` inside grep is reference to hash (ie. `{ A => 101}`). $k is equal to `A` then, and %seen hash checks if `A` key is seen for second time. Depending on that it filters the hash or not.

Comment: @PerlDeveloper `%$_` returns flat list of key/value pairs, and `keys %$_` returns list of keys. Either way, first list element would be a key.